# building web page content filter

Tags: java, filtering

i want to build a filter to block pornography sites so  i have some questions :

what tools i need ?

what are the algorithms i have to use ?  (speed , efficient )

where i can find an open source filter ?

and i want to use java .

thanks

**update :**
i need this filter for my [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392491/building-safe-search-engine-for-kids)

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a lot of time, bother, false positives and false negatives by using [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com)

Answer (score 0):

There are a LARGE number of tools that already do this. Are you *sure* you want to reinvent this wheel?

If so, the easiest (not necessarily the most efficient) is to create a proxy server that blocks content you want to block.

Building a Java proxy server has already been discussed on StackOverflow, [Write HTTP proxy in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860362/write-http-proxy-in-java)